# Integrate a partial derivative

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If we define the operator $\mathcal{G}f(t,x)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,x)$, what is the value of 
$$
\int_0^t \mathcal{G}f(s, b(s)) ds?
$$
I'm sure it's some subtlety in the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that I'm not seeing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you give more details: what kind of function (?) is $b$? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have 50 reputation to comment, so I'll answer it here: $b(s)$ is really a Standard Brownian Motion, $B(s)$, but that shouldn't matter much here.

The most promising approach was the Differentiating Under the Integral Sign, except that that would entail calculating the derivative of an integral that I can't calculate (that is, $\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(s, B(s))ds$). If it helps, the answer to the question seems to be $-f(0, B(0))$, but I'm not sure how to get it (or even if it's right).

(Feel free to add this remark as a comment and delete this post.)

Comment: Sorry I down voted by accident, I absent-mindedly thought it was a comment and meant to upvote; despite what you wrote! My vote is locked in and I can't change it, perhaps you could complain about my vote and it might be rectified.

Comment: You can edit your question with the extra information, no need to post an answer.